# Regex for exception logs

Tags: regex, parsing, logging, pcre

I am using the [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) to match exception logs with the help of the following regular expression.

**Regular Expression**

```
\[([\d -:]+)\]ERROR.*?(F:[^ ]+|F:).*?(?sx).*?(\b[a-zA-Z]*Exception\b)
```

**Exceptions logs sample**

1. Where the caught **exception is inline** (in one line) of the log statement

   ```
   [2020-03-07 01:02:37.512]ERROR [L:xx F:yy T:zz R: C: ] xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxx NullPointerException
           at com.package.name(b.java:20)
           at com.package.name.someClass.someMethod(P.java:2423)
           at com.package.name.someClass.someMethod(P.java:40)
           at com.package.name.someClass.someMethod(P.java:4054)
   ```
2. Where the caught **exception is in any other next log statement**

   ```
   [2020-03-07 01:02:37.512]ERROR [L:xx F:yy T:zz R: C: ] xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
   xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   xxxxxxxx xxxx NullPointerException
           at com.package.name(b.java:20)
           at com.package.name.someClass.someMethod(P.java:2423)
           at com.package.name.someClass.someMethod(P.java:40)
           at com.package.name.someClass.someMethod(P.java:4054)
   ```

The second sample is not matched by the mentioned regular expression.

I also tried using the [multi-line flag (\m)](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre), but it does not stop for the cases it should not match any thing

**Example**

```
[2020-03-07 01:02:37.512]ERROR [L:xx F:yy1 T:zz1 R: C: ] xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxx
[2020-03-07 01:03:37.512]ERROR [L:xx F:yy2 T:zz2 R: C: ] xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxx
[2020-03-07 01:04:37.512]ERROR [L:xx F:yy3 T:zz3 R: C: ] xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxx 
[2020-03-07 01:05:37.512]ERROR [L:xx F:yy4 T:zz5 R: C: ] NullPointerException
            at com.package.name(b.java:20)
            at com.package.name.someClass.someMethod(P.java:2423)
            at com.package.name.someClass.someMethod(P.java:40)
            at com.package.name.someClass.someMethod(P.java:4054)
```

**Expected Result**

> Group 1: **2020-03-07 01:05:37.512**, 
>   Group 2: **F:yy4**, 
>   Group 3: **NullPointerException**

**Actual Result**

> Group 1: **2020-03-07 01:02:37.512**
>   Group 2: **F:yy1**
>   Group 3: **NullPointerException**

***See how after matching the first line it doesn't stop until it finds the complete expression.***

Can someone please help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check from the start of the pattern the the next line does not start with for example `[` and a digit using a negative lookahead `(?!.*\R\[\d)` as you are using the inline modifiers `(?sx)` afterwards.

This part `(F:[^ ]+|F:)` could be shorted to matching F: and 0+ times a non whitespace char `(F:\S*)`

In the character class `[\d -:]` the hyphen is matching a range instead of only a hyphen char. If you meant to match it literally, you can for example move it to the end and add matching the dot.

```
^(?!.*\R\[\d)\[([\d :.-]+)]ERROR.*?(F:\S*)(?sx).*?\b([a-zA-Z]*Exception)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*\R\[\d)` Negative lookahead, assert the next line does not start with `[` and a digit where `\R` matches a unicode newline sequence
- `\[` Match `[`
- `([\d :.-]+)` Capture **group 1**, match any of the listed
- `]` Match `]`
- `ERROR.*?` Match ERROR and 0+ times any char except a newline
- `(F:\S*)` Capture **group 2**, Match F: and 0+ times a non whitespace char
- `(?sx).*?` Inline modifier `s` making the dot match a newline and `x` to ignore whitespace
- `\b([a-zA-Z]*Exception)\b` Capture **group 3**, Match 0+ times a char a-zA-Z followed by Exception

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6G9j02/1)

Another option without using the inline modifier `s` to make the dot match a newline could be to optionally matching all the lines that do not contain Exception after matching the the ERROR and F: part.

```
^(?!.*\R\[\d)\[([\d :.-]+)]ERROR.*?(F:\S*)(?:(?!.*Exception|.*\R\[\d).*\R)*+.*\b([a-zA-Z]*Exception)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aBVgFG/1)